# Does this sentence need "if" or "when"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

I came across this sentence:

> "There isn't an entomologist in the whole world who wouldn't give all **he has to be in my shoes today**."

This was said when a person caught a rare insect.

If "if" or "when" is placed before "he has to be in my shoes today", I think it makes sense but this sentence doesn't have them. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it says "by shoe"? Maybe "my shoes"?

Comment: Would you tell us where you found this sentence please?

Comment: The sentence makes no sense as is.    But if we change "by shoe" to "my shoes" it would mean "No entomologist in the world would be unwilling to give everything he possesses in order to be in my shoes today", that is, in order to be able to claim this discovery for himself.

Comment: Do you understand the sentence now?

Comment: No, does this sentence need “if” or “when”?

Comment: No, it does not need if or when.

Comment: I think you are confused by `he has`. This part relates to `all`, as in `all he has`, `everything he possesses`, rather than `to be` as in `he has to be`.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood them.

Comment: It might be useful to read that sentence with a "," (comma) after "give all he has".

Comment: I want to correct one of your sentences. I think you meant either *This is said when a person catches a rare insect.* or *This was said when a person caught a rare insect.*

Comment: Yes, I edit it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think your confusion might just come from not understanding the idioms in the sentence, so I'll start by paraphrasing it.

> There isn't an entomologist in the whole world who wouldn't give all he has to be in my shoes today

Since there is a double negative, we'll go ahead and reverse it. Hopefully this makes the sentence less confusing already.

> Any entomologist would give all he has to be in my shoes today.

2 of the phrases left are *give all he has* and *to be in my shoes*.

You seem to be trying to split it into *would give all* and [if/when] *he has to be in my shoes*, and you are reading "has to" as "must". This is incorrect in context.

To *give all he has* is to sacrifice anything he owns. *To be in my shoes* means  to be experiencing what the author is experiencing (catching the rare insect)

So the whole sentence simplified is:

> Any entomologist would love to be in my situation

It should be clear there is no room for if or when in that sentence.

Comment: We can also say, for example, "I wouldn't want to be in your shoes" and not just "in my shoes". It might not be clear to a learner that we can use that expression in both a positive or negative way and with other people, not just ourselves.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Yes, I am reading "has to" as "must" as you say but now I noticed it was  wrong.

Answer (score 2):

No, this sentence is fine without an "if" or "when".

I think you are being confused by an incorrect parsing of "he has to be" present in this sentence. "He has to be" can mean "he is obligated to be" or "he is required to be".

However, in this example "has" and "to be" are actually separate. In this sentence, "he has" means that which he possesses (a hint here is "all he has").

Thus, the sentence can be rewritten: "There isn't an entomologist in the whole world who wouldn't **trade everything he owns for the opportunity** to be in my shoes today."

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I am reading "has to" as "must" but now I noticed it was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> There isn't an entomologist in the whole world who wouldn't give all he has to be in my shoes today.

The sentence is fine. It does not need an *if* or *when* before *he has to be...*

We could rewrite the sentence,  slightly, and get

> There isn't an entomologist in the whole world who wouldn't give all he possesses in order to be in my shoes today.

*all he possesses* is the direct object of the verb *give*

*in order to be in my shoes today* is a prepositional phrase that provides more  information.  This prepositional phrase could be moved to other places in the sentence, such as the beginning

> In order to be in my shoes today, there  isn't an entomologist in the whole world who wouldn't give all he possesses.

with no change in meaning. The prepositional phrase could also be omitted and the sentence remain grammatical:

> There   isn't an entomologist in the whole world who wouldn't give all he possesses.

Comment: You skipped right over `to be in my shoes`, which completely removes the meaning in your final sentence. `There isn't an entomologist in the whole world who wouldn't give all he possesses...` for what? As it stands, the sentence seems to imply that entomologists are altruistic to a sacrificial degree.